# AngularJs list control - how to avoid setting form's dirty flag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

We have a mover directive that uses 2 list controls. The problem is that when I simply click on an item in the assigned items list, it makes my form dirty. I tried the following solution in the directive controller onChanged event (which is called by the second list ng-change):

```html
 $scope.onChanged = function (assigned) {
                    var currentState = $scope.form.$dirty;
                    $scope.selectedItem = assigned[0];
                    if (currentState === false)
                        $scope.form.$setPristine();
                }
```

However, the currentState is already true, so my code does nothing. How can I prevent the clicking in the list control to set form's dirty status? I found two related questions [How can I exclude controls from making form Dirty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679317/how-can-i-exclude-controls-from-making-form-dirty) and [How can I denote which input fields have changed in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641618/how-can-i-denote-which-input-fields-have-changed-in-angularjs) but it's not clear to me if I should try either of these solutions. The code checks for $scope.form.$dirty in a few places, so the best solution is somehow to make sure that clicking on the list doesn't make it dirty. I also have noDirty directive which I haven't yet tried applying to that list. I'm going to try that now.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I implemented for now is the following change in the directive:

```html
var directive = {
            controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
                $scope.upDisabled = true;
                $scope.downDisabled = true;
                $scope.assigned = null;
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.form.assignedList.$pristine = false;
                });
```

based on last answer in that thread [Prevent input from setting form $dirty angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089090/prevent-input-from-setting-form-dirty-angularjs). In my quick limited test it seems to work. I originally tried to just use our noDirtyCheck directive on the list, but somehow it didn't work in my first try, so I already switched to this solution.